# Three.js al añadir OrbitControls, no se muestra el modelo 3D ni nada

Tags: javascript, three.js

Sin añadir OrbitControls, sí que funciona, pero al añadir OrbitControls no se muestra ni el modelo 3d ¿Qué sucede?

**app.js**

```
//Variables for setup

let container;
let camera;
let renderer;
let scene;
let house;

function init() {

  container = document.querySelector(".scene");

  //Create scene
      scene = new THREE.Scene();

      const fov = 35;
      const aspect = container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight;
      const near = 0.5;
      const far = 1000;

  //Camera setup
      camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
      camera.position.set(0, 0.3, 3);

      const ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040, 2);
      scene.add(ambient);

      const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 2);
      light.position.set(50, 50, 500);
      scene.add(light);

  //Renderer
      renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true });
      renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);
      renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);

      container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


  
  //Load Model
    let loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
    loader.load('/media/3d/tubos/scene.gltf', function(gltf) {
        scene.add(gltf.scene);
        house = gltf.scene.children[0];
        animate();
    });
}


  //Controls
  const controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );




function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

init();
```

**html:**

```
<div class="scene"></div> 

<script src="/static/js/threejs/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/threejs/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/threejs/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls"></script>
<script src="/static/js/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: Creo que tu problema es bastante sencillo, te falta la extensión `/static/js/threejs/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js`

Answer (score 0):

Crea OrbitControls dentro de la función init(), porque camera y renderer no tienen valor hasta que no se ejecuta init:

```
let controls;
function init(){
//todo lo que tienes
controls =  new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
}
```